Dual boot Mint and Windows in legacy mode - Linux installation defaults to UEFI
I am trying to set up a dual boot with Linux Mint on a computer that already has Windows in legacy mode on it. I have no issues getting Linux up and running using a USB stick, but after the installation I get no option to boot Windows in the ASRock UEFI utility or in grub.
I figured this is because the Linux installation is in UEFI mode, while the Windows installation is in legacy. I have tried to follow instructions on how to install Linux in legacy mode by selecting t "USB - Generic USB" instead of the "UEFI - Generic USB" as the boot device. The live session that I start to install also seems to be running in legacy mode, and the installation menu detects Windows and gives me the option to install Linux alongside it. But after the installation runs and I reboot, the Linux version always seems to be installed in UEFI mode anyways, and Grub and UEFI utility give me the option to boot Linux, but never Windows.
I've looked for an option to enable legacy mode in the UEFI utility (which boot-repair suggests - see below), but there is no option to do so. I wonder if while rearranging partitions I've impacted the Windows boot manager in some way, because it never pops up, and instead only the ASRock UEFI utility (which I assume is not the windows boot manager). I also wonder why I am not able to install Linux in legacy mode in the first place.
I've run boot repair to create a report (see below), which hopefully provides enough info to get an answer for my question. Thanks in advance.
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241223_1740]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Linux Mint 22
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Das aktuell benutzte Betriebssystem - Linux Mint 22 on sda6
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GF110 [GeForce GTX 570] from NVIDIA Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-38-generic root=UUID=d084d715-92f4-4bef-be40-834f6d9c351c ro quiet splash
df -Th / : /dev/sda6      ext4  447G    9,6G  415G    3% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: P1.40(4.6) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0004,0003,0005
Boot0003* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)414d474f414d4e4fb3000000010000006f00540053005300540063006f007200700020004300440044005600440057002000530048002d003200320032004100420000000501090003000000007fff040002010c00d041030a0000000001010600021f03120a000100ffff00007fff040001043e00ef47642dc93ba041ac194d51d01b4ce6380052005a004200380036004200430031003900320032003400310020002000200020002000200000007fff0400414d424f
Boot0004* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)414d474f414d4e4f9b000000010000006f0053005400330031003000300030003500320034004100530000000501090002000000007fff040002010c00d041030a0000000001010600021f03120a000000ffff00007fff040001043e00ef47642dc93ba041ac194d51d01b4ce620002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200056003500410050003000420059004a0000007fff0400414d424f
Boot0005* USB   BBS(USB,,0x0)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
Boot0006* ubuntu    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,65535,0)/HD(4,MBR,0x0,0x3b7f5800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)AMBO


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda2    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda5    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda6    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0611b3a7
     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1            2048    1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2         1026048  983928831 982902784 468.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       983928832  998199295  14270464   6.8G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
sda4       998201342 1953523711 955322370 455.5G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
sda5  *    998201344  999249919   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda6       999251968 1953523711 954271744   455G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST31000524AS:;
1:1049kB:525MB:524MB:ntfs::;
2:525MB:504GB:503GB:ntfs::;
3:504GB:511GB:7306MB:ntfs::msftres;
4:511GB:1000GB:489GB:::lba;
5:511GB:512GB:537MB:fat32::boot, esp;
6:512GB:1000GB:489GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL             PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                       
├─sda1 ntfs   FAE2DB78E2DB3799                     0611b3a7-01                          System-reserviert 
├─sda2 ntfs   FA1CDDA81CDD6065                     0611b3a7-02                          Windows 10        
├─sda3 ntfs   3EAA1EE1AA1E960D                     0611b3a7-03                                            
├─sda4                                             0611b3a7-04                                            
├─sda5 vfat   62D9-3200                            0611b3a7-05                                            
└─sda6 ext4   d084d715-92f4-4bef-be40-834f6d9c351c 0611b3a7-06                                            
sdb                                                                                                       
sdc                                                                                                       
sdd                                                                                                       
sde                                                                                                       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1   467.8M   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2   180.6G  61% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3     6.4G   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda6   414.5G   2% /
efivarfs     74.1K  38% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1   fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2   fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda3   fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda6   ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda5/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid d084d715-92f4-4bef-be40-834f6d9c351c root hd0,msdos6 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon   d084d715-92f4-4bef-be40-834f6d9c351c
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda6/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d084d715-92f4-4bef-be40-834f6d9c351c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=62D9-3200  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 816,669040680 = 876,891705344  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 502,799709320 = 539,877076992  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 919,681884766 = 987,500904448  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 919,681884766 = 987,500904448  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-38-generic                  1
 921,439128876 = 989,387730944  boot/initrd.img                                1
 921,439128876 = 989,387730944  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-38-generic               1
 921,439128876 = 989,387730944  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to remove grub-efi) and reinstall the grub2 of
sda6 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because legacy Windows detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB). 

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.

sprunge.us ko ()


Change in uefi Menu boot Mode legacy only If possible.
